# C# Remove password from password protected(encrypted) excel file using the file password

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, aspose, aspose-cells

I am attempting to open a password protected excel file (versions xls, xlsx, xlsm). I need to open the files and remove the password from each file.
I have all the passwords available for the files that are to be processed.

I cant use Microsoft Interop Excel as excel must be installed on the server for this to work. I am already using Aspose.Cells to open non password protected files. But i want to be able to save the file overwrite it without its password.

Has anybody any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Code so far

```
public static void RemovePassword(string filePath, string password){
  LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions();
  loadOptions.Password = password;

  Workbook src = new Workbook(filePath, loadOptions);
  //need a way of removing the password from the file.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Unprotect](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/cells/aspose.cells/workbook/methods/unprotect) method of Workbook:

```
LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions();
loadOptions.Password = password;

Workbook workbook = new Workbook(filePath, loadOptions);
workbook.Unprotect(password);
// or workbook.Settings.Password = "";
workbook.Save(filePath);
```

Comment: is this applied to the encrypted file to be (pass) removed?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, I have noticed that your first suggestion only unprotects the workbooks structure.

```
workbook.Unprotect(password);
```

In my case i want to unencrypt an actual file that is password protected(encrypted)

The second suggestion works great thanks!

```
 workbook.Settings.Password = "";
 workbook.Save(filePath);
```

Thanks Again for your help